# It should be encouraged to provide an explanation (in comments?) for downvotes

Tags: discussion, voting, down-votes

When someone votes down on something, it is never clear why they did so. There should be some documentation that encourages downvotes to be accompanied by an explanation (in the comments?).

An example was some code I saw that does actually work, but had a downvote, which made me wonder if there was some disadvantage to the apparently working code. I'd have to implement the code, and test it significantly to find out if there is some disadvantage to it. But if someone out there knows a reason to not use the code, and doesn't provide that reason, the information is possibly gone forever.

Plus, sometimes it seems very arrogant the way people go around voting down on things on a whim, or it seems, honestly, sometimes just because they don't *like* the question for some reason. Often if feels like they get frustrated by the inexperience of the questioner.

Comment: [This already exists.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down) (you didn't give me enough time to explain. *Gah.*)

Comment: "If something is wrong, please leave a comment or edit the post to correct it." That's all I see, but it doesn't have much prominence. I feel like this and "Down-voting should be reserved for extreme cases." are widely unknown rules here.

Comment: "Down-voting should be reserved for extreme cases." interesting; that's the feeling I get when reading the help center article. However, the tooltips are much easier  on downvoting: "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful" resp. "This answer is not useful".

Comment: We're being told to leave *less* comments as part of being more welcoming.  So, now downvotes get almost no comments from me.  Apparently constructive criticism is rude.

Comment: @ fbueckert, that's contradictory, isn't it? They say downvotes should only be for extreme cases, but comments should be sparing...

Comment: You can have comments on downvotes, honesty and/or the 'Be nice' policy.  Pick any two.

Comment: Jeeze, so from a more recent question, someone viewed my profile, and from there came to look at this old question to vote it down. I'm not sure what the point is of this person doing that, or this question even being viewable, now that it's well established that it's a duplicate.

Comment: You guys really like to gang up and be brutal, well after the point has been made.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This already exists; when I downvote on a site where I have less than 2000 reputation, I get the following popup:

[image]

<sub>P.S. 1: yes, I've retracted that downvote already.

P.S. 2: this is not a 'privilege'; on Ask Different, where I am a ♦ moderator, I still get these popups.</sub>

Comment: I should pay better attention. I did not see this.

Comment: @BBaysinger Darn, that's probably why your post got so many downvotes, to be honest. I didn't downvote by the way.

Comment: I'm not worried about it. I learned a great deal.